# React-Native: Error: Unable to resolve module `SegmentedControlIOS`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xcode10

I am getting a wried error when I updated to xCode10. The error said that

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `SegmentedControlIOS` from `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: Module does not exist in the module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

I am using below version of react ana babel:

"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"react-native": "0.54.0",

I tried to reinstall the node module. But it didn't work.

Let me know if anyone have the same issue and able to sort it out.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reset caches 
as usual
it works everytime like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to get this to work?  If not, try starting the metro bundler on a separate terminal first (npm start on your project).  This sounds like what I was getting.  If you try to do npm start ios without running the metro bundler first, the working directory is set in node_modules which is why it won't find any of your files.